# Como actualizar una fecha desde spring en h2? por medio de update manejando LocalDateTime y TimeStamp

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, localdate

en el día de hoy estaba intentando resolver un inconveniente que se me presenta al momento de actualizar unos datos, los cuales manejo una db H2 en el framework de spring.

```
public void updateTech(Tech tech, UUID uuid) {
        String sql = "UPDATE TECH SET idTech = :idTech, idService = :idService, horaInicio = :horaInicio, horaFinal = :horaFinal WHERE id = :id";
        Map<String, Object> params = Map.of(
                "id", uuid,
                "idTech", tech.getIdTech(),
                "idService", tech.getIdService(),
                "horaInicio", tech.getHoraInicial(),
                "horaFinal", tech.getHoraFinal()
        );
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql,params);
    }
```

De tal manera les solicito a ustedes comunidad que me ayuden a solucionar este inconveniente.

El error es el siguiente.
`java.lang.NullPointerException: null`

Comment: `productUpdate.getImage()` que vale?

Comment: Disculpa, me equivoque de código, pero ya hice la modificación.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)